# Can you setup Outlook 2007 templates?

Tags: windows-server-2003, outlook-2007, templates

We use the same template in Word 2007 for all the employees.
When I setup a new user, I just take a copy from the server and paste it into his Application/Microsoft/Templates folder - replacing the standard.

When there needs to be a change, I change the template on the server and run a program that distributes the templates to all user profiles on the server - so next time they log in, the profile synchronizes and the template has been updated.

Now, we go with the same font in Outlook 2007. So I manually have to log into their end-user computer, open Outlook and then set the font - quite annoying.

Isn't there any way you can tie the font to some kind of template file in Outlook 2007?

**EDIT:** Or perhaps some kind of user policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook 2007 adm template dosent have any option to set the default font. But take a look [here](http://www.itexperience.net/2008/03/05/set-default-font-in-outlook-2007-with-registry/) for a way to do it with a .reg file which you could then script/deploy.

[Set default font in Outlook 2007 with registry](http://www.itexperience.net/2008/03/05/set-default-font-in-outlook-2007-with-registry/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at these docs:

[Office Customization Tool in the 2007 Office system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx#Features)

[Enforce settings by using Group Policy in the 2007 Office system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179081.aspx)

[Group Policy overview (2007 Office system)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179176.aspx)

Comment: I did, but I found nothing about font settings :)